# Powershell: add child node to XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following `XML` tree:

```
<company>
  <employees>
    <employee name="Dwight" id="e1000" department="sales">
    </employee>
    <employee name="Toby" id="e1001" department="hr">
    </employee>
    <employee name="Jim" id="e1002" department="sales">
    </employee>
  </employees>
</company>
```

And I'm trying to add a new employee named Pam, id="e1003" under department="reception".

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$fileName = "C:\code\employees.xml";

$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName); 
$newXmlEmployee = $xmlDoc.employees.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("employee"));
$newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute("name","Pam");
$newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute("id","e1003");
$newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute("department","reception"); 

$xmlDoc.Save($fileName);
```

However I'm greeted with the following error messages:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\code\testing.ps1:6 char:48
>   + $newXmlEmployee = $xmlDoc.employees.AppendChild <<<< ($xmlDoc.CreateElement("employee"));
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (AppendChild:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\code\testing.ps1:7 char:29
>   + $newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute <<<< ("name","Pam");
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetAttribute:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\code\testing.ps1:8 char:29
>   + $newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute <<<< ("id","e1003");
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetAttribute:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\code\testing.ps1:9 char:29
>   + $newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute <<<< ("department","reception");
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetAttribute:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

How would I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. You just missed the `company` node where you select the `employees`:

```
$fileName = "C:\code\employees.xml";

$xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content $fileName); 
$newXmlEmployee = $xmlDoc.company.employees.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("employee"));
$newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute("name","Pam");
$newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute("id","e1003");
$newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute("department","reception"); 

$xmlDoc.Save($fileName);
```

**Output:**

```
<company>
  <employees>
    <employee name="Dwight" id="e1000" department="sales">
    </employee>
    <employee name="Toby" id="e1001" department="hr">
    </employee>
    <employee name="Jim" id="e1002" department="sales">
    </employee>
    <employee name="Pam" id="e1003" department="reception" />
  </employees>
</company>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin! Now I need to add a child node under the employee node, I tried: $newXmlEmployee = $xmlDoc.company.employees.employee.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("address"));  but I ended up with this error:
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'AppendChild' - are nested nodes handled differently?

Comment: Its because there are multiple employee nodes - you have to select the one you want to create a child under. Please accept this answer and start another question if you don't get it to work.